# Store score in Mongo (angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, typescript

Doesn't include all of the other working but there work fine. I have a working server.js user services and controllers to register and store users in my mongoDB database. Would any one know how to store the score variable plus update the number each time the user gets it right?
The attempt I made is below.

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
export class DashboardComponent{

      makeMatch() { 
       if (this.imageMatch === this.emotionMatch) {

        this.score= this.score+ 1;

        }
```

**user.service.js**

```
function _score(_id) {

Users.findById(id, function (err, user) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  user.score += 1;

  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.send(user); // Or redirect, basically finish request.
  });
});
```

}

Comment: Are you using mongoose ?

Comment: No not using mongoose sorry

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```
function _score(userId) {
    Users.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {$inc: {score: 1}}, 
                           function (err, data) {
    // here you can handle errors and redirect or send data back to the user...
});
}
```

On the front-end , you need to have id of currently logged in user so you can call method from above with userId as a parameter. I assume that is the case  that you are looking for.
Hope it helps!